# jQuery - and operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have the following code

```
jQuery(".opsection input").live('change', function(){
```

What i want to also do is add an 'or' operator so that it runs on a 'change' function also when someone 'clicks' a text field

Any help would be grand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do it like this

```
jQuery(".opsection input").live('change click', function(){
```

This will run the function on either a change or click event.

[image: from the jquery docs]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(".opsection input").live('change click', function(){
```

Check this link for more information: http://api.jquery.com/live/